# pandas groupby based on multi-columns, but keep the most repeated duplicates number on other column

Tags: pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have a table looks below.

|  | lon | lat | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4050 | -47.812224 | -19.043365 | 1890.283215 |
| 5149 | -47.812224 | -19.043365 | 1890.283215 |
| 7316 | -47.812224 | -19.043365 | 1890.283215 |
| 8406 | -47.812224 | -19.043365 | 1890.283215 |
| 511 | -47.812014 | -19.007094 | 1813.785728 |
| 1555 | -47.812014 | -19.007094 | 1813.785728 |
| 3764 | -47.812014 | -19.007094 | 1821.363582 |
| 4846 | -47.812014 | -19.007094 | 1813.785728 |
| 29 | -47.811177 | -19.008053 | 1763.091936 |
| 1114 | -47.811177 | -19.008053 | 1763.091936 |
| 3262 | -47.811177 | -19.008053 | 1763.091936 |
| 4357 | -47.811177 | -19.008053 | 1763.091936 |
| 1436 | -47.774424 | -19.008700 | 2172.781911 |
| 2557 | -47.774424 | -19.008700 | 2174.394848 |
| 4725 | -47.774424 | -19.008700 | 2172.781911 |
| 5840 | -47.774424 | -19.008700 | 2172.781911 |
| 5211 | -47.774166 | -19.043847 | 2897.092502 |
| 6313 | -47.774166 | -19.043847 | 2897.092502 |
| 8460 | -47.774166 | -19.043847 | 2897.092502 |
| 9543 | -47.774166 | -19.043847 | 2897.092502 |
| 1679 | -47.773958 | -19.007574 | 2179.670924 |
| 2770 | -47.773958 | -19.007574 | 2179.670924 |
| 4998 | -47.773958 | -19.007574 | 2179.670924 |
| 6088 | -47.773958 | -19.007574 | 2179.670924 |
| 1937 | -47.773121 | -19.008533 | 2236.769862 |
| 3004 | -47.773121 | -19.008533 | 2236.769862 |
| 5231 | -47.773121 | -19.008533 | 2236.769862 |
| 6332 | -47.773121 | -19.008533 | 2236.769862 |

I would like to drop the duplicates by using groupby on **lon** and **lat** but keep the most repeated value on **output**

for example

| lon | lat | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -47.812224 | -19.043365 | 1890.283215 |
| -47.812014 | -19.007094 | 1813.785728 |
| -47.811177 | -19.008053 | 1763.091936 |
| -47.774424 | -19.008700 | 2172.781911 |
| -47.774166 | -19.043847 | 2897.092502 |
| -47.773958 | -19.007574 | 2179.670924 |
| -47.773121 | -19.008533 | 2236.769862 |

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the *.groupby* aggregate methods as an alternative to the Andrej's method of using *.apply* and computing for each row.

While it does solve our problem .apply methods tend to become slower for a large dataset due to lack of vectorization.

Also, reset_index works much faster when used along with 'inplace=True'.

```
%%timeit
df.groupby(['lat', 'lon']).agg(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Cool! I think I cannot use inplace=True. But it looks like it is working. Do you have any concept to use dask.Series.mode instead? pandas take a little bit longer than what I expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `.groupby` with [`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas-series-mode):

```py
x = df.groupby(["lon", "lat"])["output"].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
print(x.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
         lon        lat       output
0 -47.812224 -19.043365  1890.283215
1 -47.812014 -19.007094  1813.785728
2 -47.811177 -19.008053  1763.091936
3 -47.774424 -19.008700  2172.781911
4 -47.774166 -19.043847  2897.092502
5 -47.773958 -19.007574  2179.670924
6 -47.773121 -19.008533  2236.769862
```

Comment: Clever! This is awesome!! groupby the lon/lat as the index, and then selecting variable to apply lambda for mode. I can use this in dask!!